# Sending chars from string to byte array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, byte

Which encoding should I use to write bbb to a file as exact bytes, so if the file were opened in a hex editor, its contents would be "99 59"?

The following methods created incorrect results, as listed:

```
Byte[] bbb = { 0x99, 0x59 };
string o = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetString(bbb);
```

UTF32 (above) writes 'EF BF BD', UTF7 writes 'C2 99 59', UTF8 writes 'EF BF BD 59', Unicode writes 'E5 A6 99', ASCII writes '3F 59'

**What encoding will produce the un-changed 8-bit bytes?**

Comment: Why the C++ tag? Its C++/CLI or only C#?

Comment: Don't use any encoding.  Just write the bytes directly to the file if you don't want them to be changed.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, in order to follow your 'hard life advice', I had to re-write a few major functions, but the new method is so much cleaner and less messy with work arounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want *bytes* to be written *unencoded* to a file/stream, simply write them to the file/stream.

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"d:\temp\test.bin", bbb);
```

or

```
stream.Write(bbb, 0, bbb.Length);
```

Don't encode them at all.

Comment: Thanks Lasse, I also used your suggestion and have made some cleaner functions which deal with bytes directly.

feedBytes(byteToAddTo, byteArray);